# Exporting csv file to a different location

Tags: php, csv

I have the following function that exports the data from an array to a csv file.

```
function exportcsv($dataArray , $fileName){


    $file = fopen("$fileName.csv","w");

    fputcsv($file , $dataArray['checkedArr']); // write the columns


    foreach ($dataArray['selectedData'] as $data){ // write the data
        fputcsv($file , $data);
    }

    fclose($file);


}
```

However this file is being created in the same folder as the page I'm using it in.
How can I export this file to another folder?

Comment: Really simply: `fopen("Some/Other/Folder/name/$fileName.csv","w");`

Comment: Also please dont SPAM Tags, this is nothing to do with javascript or html. Thay are designed to gather a relevant audience, if you add irrelevant tags you just waste peoples time

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you. And you are right, my apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename in `fopen` can contain a path too. So you can try something like this:

```php
function exportcsv($dataArray, $path, $fileName){


    $file = fopen("$path/$fileName.csv","w");

    fputcsv($file , $dataArray['checkedArr']); // write the columns


    foreach ($dataArray['selectedData'] as $data){ // write the data
        fputcsv($file , $data);
    }

    fclose($file);


}
```

Keep in mind that the code above is just example code. If you are taking in the `$path` variable from the user this could lead to very bad results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
In this case, I'm not getting the path from the user, but I'm just curious, how does it lead to bad results?

Comment: @Rey Since the user controls the path, the can create a special string that will cause your function to over write any file they want.